# Use javascript to send post request

Tags: javascript, php, function, html, post

I'm currently using javascript to send a post request to a PHP file on my server:

```
function insertComment(id, status) {
   $.post("http://test.com/includes/insert.php",{id:id, status:status});
}
```

However, how can I edit my code so that when the post request is sent and when `insert.php` is loaded, the code loads the output from `insert.php` in a DIV on the original page that called the `insertComment()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your php side should output some result, and your javascript side should take the result and do something.

Example:

```
$.post("http://test.com/includes/insert.php",{id:id, status:status}, function(data) {
    $('#your_div').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Hmm, it's not replacing the div with the output from `input.php`.

Comment: @user2898075 Of course you could do anything you want, the answer is just an example:)